# NLP: Fuzzy Word/Phrase Match

Tags: nlp

I am attempting to determine if a given phrase (or a few words) is present in a relatively large text. For example:

**Text:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed
>   tristique purus, id lobortis justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
>   faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras vitae
>   neque non nibh elementum malesuada convallis et nunc. Nam vel tellus
>   nec nunc dictum dignissim eu ut felis. In Tony Starkeget efficitur
>   nunc. Cras ultrices turpis est, ac eleifend leo congue at. Donec lorem
>   diam, mattis sed sollicitudin ac, tincidunt eu sem. Curabitur vel
>   euismod lectus, sit amet tempor massa. Vivamus ut dictum nisl. Aliquam
>   et urna sit amet urna hendrerit tincidunt in a mauris. Class aptent
>   taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
>   himenaeos. Maecenas vel justo metus. Sed gravida egestas velit,
>   porttitor pulvinar justo hendrerit et.

**Phrase/Words to match in the text above:**

```
tony.stark  
t.stark  
stark_tony
starktony
```

The intention here is to infer if the person(Tony Stark) is being mentioned in a block of text.

I have read up on some fuzzy word match algorithms like `Levenshtein` and `Soundex` and also tested them in the above application but they appear to be useful for one word to one word match, not in the above application where various permutations of Tony stark is possible in both the pattern and text.

Would anyone be able to advice which fuzzy word matching algorithms would be ideal for this application, and perhaps share resources and sample code for its implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: How much training data do you have ?  (I.e.: that text where search has to be performed, what is the size of text ? )

Comment: I am restricted to publicly available datasets. The text size could range from 1000-5000 characters